# Resize iframe when its content dynamically changes (ex: ajax load)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic

I am able to resize an iframe when it's url source height changes using the following code:

```
<iframe src="source" width="625" height="100%" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"></iframe>

<script language="JavaScript">

    function autoResize(id){
        var newheight;
        var newwidth;

        if(document.getElementById){
            newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
            newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
        }

        document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
    }

</script>
```

But I don't know how I can resize it when its content changes due to a dynamic change. For example, a jQuery dynamic change.
Is there anyway to fire this autoResize() function to avoid the scroll appear during the navigation because of this dynamic content change?

Note: I can manipulate the framed site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var autoResEl = autoResize('#myElement');
setInterval( autoResEl , 400 );
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, what would be the difference between using setInterval() or an eventListener oriented solution? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you can manipulate the JS in your iframe (included) page. In that case you could sniff for changes bound to `iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument`

Comment: Yes, I'm framing a page of my own so it won't be a problem to manipulate the framed page. Could you specify a little how to do it? Thanks.